# How to manage a PHP list with javascript trigger

Tags: javascript, php, list, dynamic

I'm on a php(symfony4)/twig application. On a part which dynamically show a list of alerts in php.
I need to put checkboxes to manage this list (show/hide some alerts).

**twig file :**

```
  <div class="x_title" style="display: flex">
       <h2 class="text-uppercase">
            <span id="nbAlerts">-</span> alerte(s)
       </h2>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
       <label class="container-checkbox">Required action
           <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="red_action">
           <span class="checkmark checkMarkRed"></span>
       </label>

       <label class="container-checkbox">Major action
           <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="orange_action">
           <span class="checkmark checkMarkOrange"></span>
       </label>

       <label class="container-checkbox">Action mineure
           <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="yellow_action">
           <span class="checkmark checkMarkYellow"></span>
       </label>
  </div>
  <div class="x_content">
     <div id="AlertListContainer">
          /* place where the alerts' list is dynamically appears */
     </div>
  </div>
```

**AlertList file**

```
{% if toAlert is empty %}
    no alert to display

{%  else %}
    <ul class="to_do">
        {% for oAlert in toAlert %}
            {% set alertColor = '' %}

            {% if oAlert.type.level.label == 'High' %}
                {% set alertColor = 'red' %}
            {% elseif oAlert.type.level.label == 'Medium' %}
                {% set alertColor = 'orange' %}
            {% elseif oAlert.type.level.label == 'Low' %}
                {% set alertColor = 'yellow' %}
            {% endif %}
               <li class="border_{{ alertColor }}" 
                   onclick="window.location.href='{{ oAlert.link }}'">
                   <p class="tag-notif text-uppercase text-center">
                       {{ oAlert.type.level.label }}
                   </p>
                   <p class="text-notif">
                       {{ oAlert.content }}
                   </p>
               </li>

       {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% endif %}
```

So, when only the "required action" checkbox is checked, i want to see only the alerts : oAlert.type.level.label == 'High'.

I did it this in my javascript, but i know it's wrong...

```
$(function () {
     $("#red_action").click(function () {
         if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
             $({{oAlert.type.level.label == 'High'}}).show();
         } else {
             $({{oAlert.type.level.label == 'High'}}).hide();
         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did't find better approch that doesn't change your code so much so i wrote this , this will work if don't then do some tweaks

```
<div class="x_title" style="display: flex">
       <h2 class="text-uppercase">
            <span id="nbAlerts">-</span> alerte(s)
       </h2>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
       <label class="container-checkbox">Required action
           <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="red_action" data-checkcolor="red">
           <span class="checkmark checkMarkRed"></span>
       </label>

       <label class="container-checkbox">Major action
           <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="orange_action" data-checkcolor="orange">
           <span class="checkmark checkMarkOrange"></span>
       </label>

       <label class="container-checkbox">Action mineure
           <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="yellow_action" data-checkcolor="yellow">
           <span class="checkmark checkMarkYellow"></span>
       </label>
  </div>
  <div class="x_content">
     <div id="AlertListContainer">
          /* place where the alerts' list is dynamically appears */
     </div>
  </div>

{% if toAlert is empty %}
    no alert to display

{%  else %}
    <ul class="to_do">
        {% for oAlert in toAlert %}
            {% set alertColor = '' %}

            {% if oAlert.type.level.label == 'High' %}
                {% set alertColor = 'red' %}
            {% elseif oAlert.type.level.label == 'Medium' %}
                {% set alertColor = 'orange' %}
            {% elseif oAlert.type.level.label == 'Low' %}
                {% set alertColor = 'yellow' %}
            {% endif %}
               <li data-color="{{ alertColor }}" hidden class="border_{{ alertColor }}" 
                   onclick="window.location.href='{{ oAlert.link }}'">
                   <p class="tag-notif text-uppercase text-center">
                       {{ oAlert.type.level.label }}
                   </p>
                   <p class="text-notif">
                       {{ oAlert.content }}
                   </p>
               </li>

       {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% endif %}
```

```
<script>
     $("[data-checkcolor]").on('change',function () {
        var color = $(this).attr('data-checkcolor');
         if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
             $("[data-color='"+color+"']").prop('hidden',false);
         } else {
             $("[data-color='"+color+"']").prop('hidden',true);
         }
     });
</script>
```

Comment: It almost works :D
When i check/uncheck, the alerts appears and disapears like i want.
How can i see all of the list when the page is charged, (and the checkboxes all checked) ?
And only after uncheck checkboxes to hide the alerts i don't wan't to see ?

After that, this will be absolutely perfect :)

Comment: remove the hidden attribute from <li> to show all alerts by default. to check checkboxes on page load, add 'checked' attribute